# Vue.js JS Array value to be added to class name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code in Vue.js

```
<li v-for = "record in records" v-bind:key= "record.id">
                  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">date_range</i><h6>{{record.record_date}}</h6> &nbsp &nbsp <span class="chip white-text">
```

I want to add {{record.record_status_color}} to the span class="chip white-text"

so it should change color depending upon the value of record.record_status_color

how do I do this in Vue.js

basically it should look like this assuming that {{record.record_status_color}} is green

```
<span class="{{record.record_status_color}} chip white-text">

<span class="green chip white-text">
```

Comment: :class="record.record_status_color"

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally not a fan of having `class` and `:class` on one element. You can do all 3 with `:class`

```
<span :class="[record.record_status_color, 'chip', 'white-text']">
```

Equals

```
<span class="green chip white-text">
```

Comment: Disagreed. `:class` should be reserved for dynamically adding/removing/changing class names, not for adding static class names.

Comment: Happy to be disagreed with, it's why i prefaced my answer as being preference. Also helps to know all of the ways to achieve the answer to question.

Comment: @connexo He is using a dynamic class with `record.record_status_color`, adding the others at the end just saves having multiple class attributes against the HTML element. IMO this is the correct approach.

Comment: Having both `class` and `:class` on the same element never leads to multiple `class` attributes on the same element. Internally `:class` works using `DOMNode.classList.add()/remove()`, so this never is a problem.

Comment: I'm not on about the rendered dom element, I mean during dev - It could lead to confusion. Each to their own but if a developer came to my code, I'd prefer him to see it as a standard HTML element is to which you'd never have multiple classes. Just my preference as are yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both `class="..."` and dynamic binding `:class="..."` on the same element, where classes listed in `class="..."` are always on the element, and classes in `:class="..."` depend on your model and are dynamically added/removed as per what's going on in the model.

In the `:class` binding you can bind either `String`, `Object` or `Array`:

```
<span class="green chip white-text" :class="record.record_status_color">
```

where `record.record_status_color: 'green'">` and some CSS defining the looks for `.green` elements.

Object use for multiple classes, or for applying conditional usage of the class:

```
classObject: {
  active: true,
  'text-danger': false
}
```

and then

```
<div :class="classObject"></div>
```

which would resolve to

```
<div class="active"></div>
```

You can also pass an Array to `:class`:

```
data: {
  activeClass: 'active',
  errorClass: 'text-danger'
}
```

and then

```
<div :class="[ activeClass, errorClass ]"></div>
```

which will render to

```
<div class="active text-danger"></div>
```

You can even use expressions in the Array syntax:

```
<div :class="[isActive ? activeClass : '', errorClass]"></div>
```

or

```
<div :class="[(new Date().getFullYear() > 2018) ? activeClass : '', errorClass]"></div>
```

More information on the subject, along with these examples, can be found in the official documentation.

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<span class="green chip white-text" :class="[record.record_status_color]">
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html